# How to properly setup openssl CA to generate ssl client certificates

Tags: openssl

I am configuring my first CA. It purpose will be to issue certificates for our clients, who will use them to access our EDI service over https. So I need to generate ssl client certificates. Whole process of signing certificates works by now, and the certificates can be successfully used to access our service, but I am worried about one thing:

The generated certificate purposes are way to generic:

```
$ openssl x509 -purpose  -noout -in client.crt.pem
Certificate purposes:
SSL client : Yes
SSL client CA : No
SSL server : Yes
SSL server CA : No
Netscape SSL server : Yes
Netscape SSL server CA : No
S/MIME signing : Yes
S/MIME signing CA : No
S/MIME encryption : Yes
S/MIME encryption CA : No
CRL signing : Yes
CRL signing CA : No
Any Purpose : Yes
Any Purpose CA : Yes
OCSP helper : Yes
OCSP helper CA : No
```

I feel that there should be no other purposes but SSL client and S/MIME signing in my case. Am I wrong and this should stay as it it?

If I am correct and I should disable other purposes, what should I put in my openssl.cnf config?

Here is my current config (stripped a little bit):

```
[ CA_edi ]
# here was directory setup and some other stuff, cut it for clarity
x509_extensions = usr_cert      # The extentions to add to the cert

name_opt    = ca_default        # Subject Name options
cert_opt    = ca_default        # Certificate field options
# Extension copying option: use with caution.
# copy_extensions = copy
# stripped rest of config about validity days and such

[ usr_cert ]

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
nsCertType = client, email
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, keyAgreement
```

What am I doing wrong that the certs generated allows for server usage?

Comment: Review "cert_opt = ca_default" which appears to be creating an override.

Comment: This seems like a good question, years later and no answer?

Comment: Yeah, no answer. I have not figured it out myself. But our EDI beta test are in progress and I will have to work it out in near future for the production version.

Comment: I've taken my best stab at an answer below, but if you can include a copy of the output from `openssl x509 -text -nameopt multiline -certopt no_sigdump -certopt no_pubkey -noout -in one_of_your_client_certificates.pem` and the extensions section from your `openssl.cnf` file, I'll see if I can provide more specific advice.

Answer (score 6):

You're right to be concerned about "CRL signing", "Any Purpose CA", and "OCSP Helper", these are usually reserved for CA certificates or certificates specifically issued for signing certificate revocation lists (CRLs, a list of certificates that are invalid), or running an OCSP server (similar to CRLs, but an online service that provides validity status for certificates).

The relevant OpenSSL documentation page is for the [x509 command](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html#) and [x509v3_config](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509v3_config.html#)

Here's the OpenSSL configuration I use for generating client certificates:

```
[user]
basicConstraints = critical,CA:FALSE
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth,emailProtection
subjectAltName=email:copy
crlDistributionPoints = URI:http://www.rgweb.org/ca/rgweb-ca.crl
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always
authorityInfoAccess = caIssuers;URI:http://www.rgweb.org/ca/rgweb-ca.cer
```

I'll take you through it line-by-line:

The `basicConstraints` is set as critical, which means "reject this certificate if you don't understand this bit", and specifies that the certificate is **not a CA**. Even if someone uses software to issue a certificate from this certificate, it won't ever be trusted.

The extended key usage is not essential, but some software requires it be present and have a particular purpose listed. This lists client authentication (what you're talking about) and also S/MIME email signing & encryption; you can safely remove the S/MIME purpose if you don't need it.

`subjectAltName` allows you to include information about the subject that you can't include in the `subject` field. It's also used in web server certificates to include domain names that the certificate may be used for other than the domain specified in the subject's common name attribute; these certificates are referred to as SAN (subject alternative name) certificates. It's common practice to include the email address in the `subjectAltName` rather than in the subject; you don't have to include an email address at all, and can omit the extension.

`crlDistributionPoints` lists the places that the CRL for the issuing authority is available; it tells software that's trying to validate the certificate "here's where to go to see if this certificate is still valid." For Internet use, a `http://` URL is probably best (CRLs are digitally signed, so there's no need for `https`, and it may cause trust loop issues).

`authorityKeyIdentifier` is usually the SHA-1 hash of the issuing CA's public key (though it may be other values). If you include this extension, the value **must match the value of `subjectKeyIdentifier` in the issuing CA certificate**.

`authorityInfoAccess` is a bit like `crlDistributionPoints` but it specifies where to get the issuing CA *certificate* rather than the CRL. This is useful if you have a long chain of trust: e.g. CA-1 issues CA-2, which issues CA-3, which issues the certificate; software attempting to verify the certificate can use this extension to get the CA-3 certificate, then use the value in that certificate to get the CA-2 certificate, etc. Usually, the certificate chain (in this case, the CA-2 certificate and CA-3 certificate) is bundled alongside the subject's certificate (e.g. in an SSL transaction, or S/MIME email). I don't know of any software that uses this extension, but I don't know that it's not commonly used, either. It's commonly included in certificates.

Of all that, you only really *need* the `basicConstraints` and `extendedKeyUsage`; basic constraints really, really *must* be critical (or you've just handed out CA certificates!), and extended key usage generally isn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already lost my hope. I will read into it later today and get back to you as soon as I can.